# How to wait until selenium completes its navigation?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, pageload

Ok here my code and but it immediately executes

```
        private static ChromeDriver mainDriver;
        mainDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(srFetchUrl);
        string srPageSource = mainDriver.PageSource;
```

I have to get the source code after the page is actually navigated to new page and page is loaded

Comment: What's `googleTranslateMainDriver`? `mainDriver.getPageSource()` should only return once a page has been completely loaded in Selenium 2.0. Of course, post-load modifications of the page from JavaScript are not handled.

Comment: @dhke yes it is mainDriver. also it returns old page's source code when i navigate

Comment: Why don't you try the pageloadtimeout? driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method, this will wait until page loads completely and you can add your expected time to page load.

```
public void E_WaitForPageLoad() throws Exception
{
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    //This loop will rotate for 100 times to check If page Is ready after every 1 second.
    //You can replace your if you wants to Increase or decrease wait time.
    int waittime;
    waittime = 60;
    for (int i=0; i<waittime; i++)
    { 
       try 
        {
           Thread.sleep(1000);
        }catch (InterruptedException e) {} 
        //To check page ready state.
        if (js.executeScript("return document.readyState").toString().equals("complete"))
        { 
            //System.out.println("Wait for Page Load : "+js.executeScript("return document.readyState").toString());
            break; 
        }   
    }
    System.out.println("\nWeb-Page Loaded.");
}
```

Thank You,
Ed D, India.

Answer (score -1):

Specify , implicit or explicit wait till the element in the page is loaded.

refer this [link](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/c-sharp/advance-explicit-webdriver-waits-in-c/) for C# wait syntax

Comment: currently it gives me the previous page source code. with this way it can still give the previous page's source code?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. If there's something specific in the link you posted, please post the code here.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG as I understand your question, you need to navigate to next page and get the source code of that page right ? correct me if i am Wrong.

Now as per my understanding the problem is due to immediate execution it's not getting the next page source code, so if we specify considerable amount of wait till the next page is loaded and you can execute the command to get the source code.

Comment: @JeffC as I am not sure on the syntax of C#, i have specified the link,this link will give idea on wait syntax, my apologies if my understanding to the question is wrong.